# What is the difference between simply action and action creator in reactjs and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

After reading redux official docs, i'm unable to get the différence between action creator function and simply action. 
they are complementary ?

Comment: Here's a link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405571/what-are-differences-between-redux-react-redux-redux-thunk

Comment: It's a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405571/what-are-differences-between-redux-react-redux-redux-thunk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are differences between redux, react-redux, redux-thunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405571/what-are-differences-between-redux-react-redux-redux-thunk)

Answer (score 2):

**Action** is message that we send to redux store. It can be of any type like mostly object which contain payload and action type

**Action** creator is function which create and return function dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

**Actions** are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store. **Actions** are plain JavaScript objects. **Actions** must have a type property.

**Action creators** are exactly that—functions that create actions.

Answer (score 0):

An action in Redux is only a function. That it. It has a type and a potential payload.

Once an action is "dispatched" using redux dispatch method or u can do the easier bindActionCreators which takes care of the dispatch call for you, redux reducers are all fired and then we check for a match in the switch tree of the reducers.

If there is a match in the reducers the new state in the reducer is set and it triggers a render update on react.