# React.js Redux and react-redux, use them both or only one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react app, I want to use redux,

now there are standard redux and react-redux library, what would be the best approach how to use them? I have seen them both used in many apps, would it be too tedious or complicated to use only redux? And can I use react-redux without redux anyway?

is there maybe any other simplified redux based architecture library for react out there?=

Comment: They do different things. `redux` handles the store, and `react-redux` handles the connection between the store and the components. You'll most likely need both (which is why you always see them together). You definitely can't use `react-redux` without `redux` tho.

Comment: you can look at What are diffrences https://stackoverflow.com/a/38405713/8511126

Comment: thanks guys, that clarifies the scope / usage of both packages a bit more... One more question: Would I have to use redux-thunk mandatorily in addition if I use async operations in actions, like e.g a database fetch?

Comment: redux-thunk or redux-saga are the most popular libraries for handling side effects like async operations. You will most likely need one of those